# how to change the size of design xml screen size in Android studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

so I am trying to use scroll view, and there is a lot of views that will be nested  in my scroll view.

so I want to adjust it in the design tab xml not in the text tab xml using constraint layout, it will be great if I can set and see it in the designer xml tab.

in iOS development I can change the height of 'canvas' design screen like the image below, the screen 'canvas' on the left is higher than the screen canvas on the right side, so I can set the constraint and see all the views in the design before running the app.

[image]

so how to change the screen canvas size of xml in Android Studio? I have tried to search but I can't find it because maybe I don't know what it is called in Android studio

Comment: select a different device to change the preview size. It is known as layout preview

Comment: you likely can't do that.

Comment: you can actually scroll in preview just place your mouse pointer inside view and scroll using scroller wheel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little icon at the bottom right of the design view that looks like two lines on horizontal that can help you create the design view how you like to whichever size.[image]

Comment: I know it's been a while but I have a followup question: after dragging that handle, is there a way to get the size I ended up with in pixels?

Comment: HOLY JESUS THIS IS IMPOSSIBLE TO USE!

Answer (score 1):

There is a "zoom in" button available at the bar above but sometimes it not working , then try decreasing the size of build:sync messages at the bottom and attributes on the right , it worked for me.